# I have two same html input text id but different div how to get the two id values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create two div [ Div1 and Div2] have   two same html input text id. how to get the two different div with text type id values in jquery.

when i click div 2 button it show out put first div text id values. please help this. thanks.

```js
function GetDiv1Value() {
    alert($('#TestId').val());
}

function GetDiv2Value() {
    alert($('#TestId').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIv1">
        Div1:   
        <input type="text" id="TestId" />
         <input type="button" onclick="GetDiv1Value();"value="Div 1" />
  </div>

  <div id="Div2">
        Div2:   
        <input type="text" id="TestId" />
         <input type="button" onclick="GetDiv2Value();" value="Div 2" />
  </div>
```

Comment: `ID`s should be unique, use the same `class` instead.

Comment: the problem is you set same id on both input, just split it to two different id .

Comment: "when i click div 2 button it show out put first div text id values. please help this. thanks." ? I got a headache trying to understand !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ID` should be unique, use the same class instead.

However if you want to go with duplicate id,

> You can apply parent `div` id in selector which is unique.

Please check below code:

```js
function GetDiv1Value() {
    alert($('#DIv1 #TestId').val());
}

function GetDiv2Value() {
    alert($('#Div2 #TestId').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DIv1">
        Div1:   
        <input type="text" id="TestId" value='this is one' />
         <input type="button" onclick="GetDiv1Value();" value="Div 1" />
  </div>

  <div id="Div2">
        Div2:   
        <input type="text" id="TestId" value='this is two' />
         <input type="button" onclick="GetDiv2Value();" value="Div 2" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir.. I was expecting this solution... and i got this from you.. appreciate it.